# Dynamic Bootstrap Dropdown angular js

Tags: angularjs

fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/3DS49/162/
HTML

`<bs-dropdown data-menu-type="button" select-val="selected_status = selectedVal"
preselected-item="selected_status" data-dropdown-data="statuses"></bs-dropdown>  &nbsp; Selected Value : {{selected_status}}`

app

```
function Main($scope, $rootScope) {
$scope.statuses = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Low"        
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Normal"        
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "High"        
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: "Urgent"        
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: "Immediate"        
}];
$scope.selected_status = 3;}

angular.module('pof', []).directive('bsDropdown', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        items: '=dropdownData',
        doSelect: '&selectVal',
        selectedItem: '=preselectedItem'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var html = '';
        switch (attrs.menuType) {
            case "button":
                html += '<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn button-label btn-info">{{selected}}</button><button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>';
                break;
            default:
                html += '<div class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="javascript:;">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b>{{selected}}</a>';
                break;
        }
        html += '<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li ng-repeat="item in items"><a tabindex="-1" data-ng-click="selectVal(item)">{{item.name}}</a></li></ul></div>';
        element.append($compile(html)(scope));
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.items.length; i++) {
            if (scope.items[i].id === scope.selectedItem) {
                scope.bSelectedItem = scope.items[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        scope.selectVal = function (item) {
            scope.selected = item.name;
            scope.doSelect({
                selectedVal: item.id
            });
        };
        scope.selectVal(scope.bSelectedItem);
    }
};
```

});

can any one tell how to choose default option that will not be available in items array.
This fiddle is only having an option to choose from the array only, if we wan't to show a default option as choose or select.

Comment: cant see link to fiddle?

Comment: added link and code as well @jithin